# Talend (Data Integration) - List all jobs which use a specific table

Tags: search, talend

I have to do some update in a Talend's project, and i was wondering if we can list all the jobs which use a specific table (for example i want to list all the jobs which use the tables "employees") .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, i found a solution. 
I go to the folder where i install Talend, then "workspace > MyProject > Process" and i do a research "Employees" with 
Advanced Options > File Contents. 
[image]

This methods is not perfect, it allow me to list all the jobs which are using the table Employees but id doesn't allow me to replace the words Employees for example.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> will open a "find a job" box, where you can search a job by it's name or name regex only and open it. Text search can not be evaluated in Talend open studio.

Though you can always use "grep" command from the command line for such search inside process folder.

Comment: I didn't know the shortcut Shift+ ctrl+J so it's always helpful for me or for anyone who will see this post.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the subscription product, it includes 'impact analysis' option that you can run on a table, from the Metadata Repository (in Repository>Metadata>right click on the table schema>Impact Analysis) .

It will give you all the jobs currently using a table, as long as you use the metadata from the repository on your job.

Comment: We've all seen jobs that not use metadata, so the best we can do is search for the table name in the files located under the process folder of the workspace. That we can trust.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.talend.com/reader/RK~CAb9nJ1erxR8SrBbKoQ/GoqgqvPBIzBsrVsCxjZA7g

Talend Administration Console>Repository Browser>full text searcher